# Is it possible to return a dictionary's values (list of objects) and call their __str__ function instead of printing their memory address?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Hey the question title might be a bit confusing. So basically I want to print out a dictionary with the keys and it's values, so I know to call dictionary.items() but I want it to print out using the object's **str** function instead of printing the memory address.

My Player object

```
class Player():

    def __init__(self, id, name, position):
        self.player_id = id
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

So I have a dictionary -

```
depth_chart = {}
```

That I insert the player objects into as a list.

```
def addPlayer(player, position):
    # Function to add player to depth chart.

    if position not in depth_chart:
        depth_chart[position] = []
        depth_chart[position].append(player)

    else:
        depth_chart[position].append(player)
```

So I eventually might have something like this -

```
depth_chart = {
   'shooting_guard': [PlayerObject1, PlayerObject2],

   'center': [PlayerObject3],

   'point_guard': [PlayerObject4]

}
```

Now here's my problem if I call depth_chart.items() I want it to return me something like

```
[('shooting_guard', ['John', 'Joseph'] ), ('center', ['Alex']), ('point_guard': ['Sean'] ]
```

But right now it just returns me the memory address of the Player objects. Is there a way to call the **str** function or another method to print out the player object names? I do have a function I can do to get it to look like how I want but I'm not sure if there's an easier way? How that function looks -

```
def getFullDepthChart():
    # Function to print out all the positions in the depth chart

    all_players = []
    for items in depth_chart.items():
        temp = []
        position = items[0]
        player_array = items[1]
        for players in player_array:
            temp.append(players.name)
        all_players.append((position, temp))
    return all_players
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `__repr__` to return the player's name:

```
class Player:
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def getFullDepthChart():
    # Function to return all positions in the depth chart

    all_players = [(position,
                    [player.name for player in players])
                    for pos, players in depth_chart.items()]

    return all_players
```

Comment: Thanks, while it wasn't exactly what I was looking for it improved on my juvenile code by your way of list comprehensions!